# Does VMWare Fusion (5) use logical CPU cores before physical ones?

Tags: macos, cpu, vmware-fusion, multi-core

I have a Intel Core i7 quad core CPU in my Mac Book Pro. The processor supports hyperthreading, so I have 4 physical CPU core and 8 logical ones.

Now, when I *assign 4 CPU cores to a virtual machine* in VMWare Fusion (version 5, if it matters), does VMWare Fusion use the physical ones before using the logical ones?

I.e. which solution will be used (PC = physical core, LC = logical core):

- PC1-LC1, PC2-LC1, PC3-LC1, PC4-LC1
- or: PC1-LC1, PC1-LC2, PC2-LC1, PC2-LC2

Does this even matter?

Comment: Since VMWare Fusion is hosted on OSX (rather than being a bare-metal hypervisor) I expect it depends entirely on how OSX manages physical and logical cores.